# Calling a method in a separate class from the whenever schedule.rb

Tags: ruby, cron, whenever

I am trying to call a method from a whenever schedule like this:

**schedule.rb**:

```
require '../app/bots/task_bot'

every 1.minute do
    runner 'TaskBot.test_robot'
end
```

And I have a class called `TaskBot` placed inside the directory `app/bots/task_bot.rb`. It looks like this:

**task_bot.rb**:

```
class TaskBot
    def test_robot()
        logger = Logger.new('log/robot.log')
        logger.debug("TEST")
    end
end
```

Then I ran the command `whenever --update-crontab` and verified that the crontab is updated by using `crontab -l`. Crontab was updated but I don't see the Logger being executed every minute. I'm new to this, am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

`test_robot` is an **instance** method but you are trying to execute it as a **class** method; in order for it to work you have two options:

1. Create the `TaskBot` object first and then call `test_robot`:

   ```
   every 1.minutes do
     runner 'TaskBot.new.test_robot'
   end
   ```
2. Create a **class** method, and do not modify schedule code (i prefer this way):

   ```
   class TaskBot
     def self.test_robot
       logger = Logger.new('log/robot.log')
       logger.debug("TEST")
     end
   end
   ```

Comment: Thanks. I tried 2) but the cron logs printed this: `uninitialized constant TaskBot`. Is it because of the directory the class is in?

Comment: @Dinuka Probably, in which directory is _schedule.rb_ file? In order for your code to work properly it would need to be in another directory at the same level that _app_ directory is.

Comment: schedule is inside `config/` since that's where whenever generates it. TaskBot is inside `app/bots/task_bot`. Anyway I could require the taskbot file inside schedule?

Comment: @Dinuka Are you using Rails? If so, you don't need to require anything, Rails will load everything inside _app_ directory; but maybe you added that file and haven't restarted your app. Try removing the `require` line and restarting your app.